# How to disable confirm dialog when finding and replacing multiple occurrences in the VS Code Search View?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if I open the search panel and type in a search key and an expression to replace with and press the keyboard shortcut that runs the replace all action, a dialog opens saying "Replace _ occurrences across _ files" and a button to Confirm.

Is there a setting to disable this dialog and directly replace all?

Comment: the problem is you can't UNDO this across all files, so VSC asks if you are sure, Notepad++ also asks that question

Comment: Actually, an Undo in one of the modified files will undo them all, so it isn't that.  I think it is just an abundance of caution, so you REALLY mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, such settings for confirmation dialogues have "confirm" in their name/ID. I don't see a setting for disable this particular confirmation dialogue, which leads me to believe that there isn't one.

I didn't find a feature-request ticket in the top search results of googling `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues disable confirm dialog for replace all`. I suggest that you [raise one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).